# When installing mySQL on windows 10 a pop up with "No Packages Found" error message appears

Tags: mysql, installation

I was using mySQL workbench for a few days now until today when it wouldn't connect to server. Searching through a quite few answers on google I went ahead with the complete uninstall.
So I deleted it from my "Apps and features" then followed by deleting "mySQL" folder from the below folders:

- Program Files
- Program Files (x86)
- ProgramData
- Users

I even cleaned up the Recycling Bin from whatever had sql in the title.
Restarted the laptop.

Then downloaded this version:
[mySQL Installer 8.0.23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfiPB.png)
After I open the file the installation wizard pops up which prompts me to choose one of the Setup types (Developer Default, Server Only, Client Only, Full, Custom).
[mySQL Setup type screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiIZA.png)

When I click on "Developer Default" and press "Next" button it returns this message
[No packages found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihURH.png)

When I click on "Custom" setup type then I end up with this pop up window: [Select Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhHiq.png) which has blank field in "Available Products".

From what I found on the internet there were suggestions of deleting this file C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\Manifest\Products.xml , but I don't even have a Manifest folder and I don't have file named Products either.. here are all files that come with the mySQL package [MySQL Installer for Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ9Dy.png)

I also tried unistalling the above version and have installed the older version, but ended up with the same results.. no products found. So I again uninstalled the older version and installed this MySQL Installer 8.0.23 again.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you,
Olga

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue (version 8.0.23). To get the installer to work, I had to delete the entire folder: 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL'.  After I did that, I reran the installer and it worked. Seems like a bug in the installer.

Answer (score 0):

**Same error i got, but after some time i got the reason!**

*the reason is my network problem,*

**so kindly check your connection to avoid this error**